# Issue when using modulus operator or other arithmetic operands in a class

Tags: c++, class, modulus

Hello im having an issue when using the % operator in my class method functions.The console window pop ups but then another window opens when saying "  ".exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. any idea? Heres the line of code of when i omit works fine.

```
r = gnumer % gden;
```

Comment: Can we have more information please? What is `gnumer`, what is `gden`?

Comment: oh right , all three variables are longs

Comment: if you have a descent debuger, show us the call stack

Comment: @user954004 Can you please add this information to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `gden` zero?  Modulus by zero is just as bad as dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

It may because gden ==0, or if gden is not a global or static variable, did you forget to initialize it?